# How to get selected Backlog Item in Backlogs window?

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, backlog

I am developing a VSTS extension.
I have added a panel in the backlog window.
I want to get the selected backlog item on the click of a button in backlog panel.

I cannot use `WorkItemFormService` as there is no active work item.
Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn’t such API, you can’t get selected backlog through VSTS extension.

Comment: Is there any alternative method to get it ?

Comment: As far as I know, no, there isn't.